# Spark requests for more core than asked when calling POST livy batch api in azure synapse

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, azure-synapse, spark-submit, livy

I have an azure synapse spark cluster with 3 nodes of 4 vCores and 32 GB memory each. I am trying to submit a spark job using azure synapse Livy batch APIs. The request looks like this,

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://<synapse-workspace>.dev.azuresynapse.net/livyApi/versions/2019-11-01-preview/sparkPools/<pool-name>/batches?detailed=true' `
--header 'cache-control: no-cache' `
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <Token>' `
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' `
--data-raw '{
    "name": "T1",
    "file": "folder/file.py",
    "driverMemory": "1g",
    "driverCores": 1,
    "executorMemory": "1g",
    "executorCores":1,
    "numExecutors": 3
}'
```

The response I get is this,

```
{
    "TraceId": "<some-guid>",
    "Message": "Your Spark job requested 16 vcores. However, the pool has a 12 core limit. Try reducing the numbers of vcores requested or increasing your pool size."
}
```

I cannot figure out why is it asking for 16 cores. Shouldn't it ask for 4 (3 * 1 + 1) cores?

**Update**:
I tried changing the node pool size to 3 nodes each of 8 vCores and 64 GB memory. And, with this configuration,

```
{
    "name": "T1",
    "file": "folder/file.py",
    "driverMemory": "1g",
    "driverCores": 1,
    "executorMemory": "1g",
    "executorCores": 1,
    "numExecutors": 6
}
```

It requests for 28 cores (even for executorCores 2,3,4). And if I change executorCores to 5,6,7 or 8, it will request for 56 cores.

Comment: Did you try submitting the spark job via the synapse portal? Does it work that way?

Comment: I hadn't tried that. But now that I have looked at it, many things are clear. I will post that as an answer.

Comment: When I tried submitting the job via the portal on 3 nodes each of 8 vCores and 56 GB memory, the UI tells me I have only two options for executor configurations.
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mENdU.png
It seems like a problem from the synapse side. So to conclude no matter how many resources I ask, it will always request maximum resources(4,8,16... cores).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic used by Livy for calculating vcore usage is not the same as it is in yarn.  Livy appears to be "rounding" up your driverCores and executorCores in multiples of 4 or 8 without telling us. This unexpected behavior seems like a bug, whenever a customer encounters it.

Whereas the YARN cluster manager would have accepted smaller jobs, the small ones aren't able able to get past the door of the custom Livy implementation (it is all home-grown code from the Synapse-Spark team).

On 9/27/2023 I received the following update from CSS.  I wish I could share the ICM # or BUG # but those are fairly hard to come by.  I believe the "PG" which is mentioned here is referring to the "jobs-service" engineers within the Synapse Spark team.

**"We have an update from the PG team that the microservice responsible for rounding off the cores to the nearest available size has been modified to accommodate smaller container sizes, we have also deployed the new bits and currently the release has reached the east us region, so it will be complete shortly and you will be able to see the improvements."**

To make a long story short, it is possible that Livy will start behaving better, when submitting jobs for arbitrarily-sized executors and drivers.  It is also possible that this will cause the spark pool to auto-size up to the max number of nodes (via Yarn).  I am not holding my breath, until I see it happening myself.  Hope this makes sense.  I will try to update my answer after my deployments and tests are completed.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that the Spark team decided to go another way with this.  When they said they were going to "accommodate smaller container sizes", it appears what they meant is that they would ensure that Livy/Yarn agree on the number of vCores. Yet they will **STILL** round up to multiples of 4 or 8.

I asked for documentation, given that the rounding behavior is non-intuitive.  The Livy API shouldn't receive a custom job, with certain specifications and then arbitrarily change the size of the executors.  I'm guessing they are spending all their time on Fabric and just don't care.

Answer (score 0):

From the portal there is no way to do what you are trying to do.

But you can still submit spark job by specifying driver (core and memory) and executor (core and memory). For example with something like this: [Submit Spark job in Azure Synapse from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70956627/submit-spark-job-in-azure-synapse-from-java/70957051#70957051)

Using the above code, I am able to submit 9 concurrent jobs (with 1 driver and 1 executor, both consuming a single core) in 3 node Medium instances (8 cores each, though only 7 are available for use as 1 is reserved for hadoop daemon).

Comment: When you say you were able to submit, do you mean you received the response or you actually checked the synapse workspace and in the monitor tab, you could see all 9 jobs running concurrently? In my case, I get the response but jobs are queued except one.

Comment: Yes. I checked my synapse monitor tab and verified it.